# How to access an objects set and get methods when it is in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, setter, getter

So I have this code here:

```
List<XMLMessage> xmlMessageList = new ArrayList<XMLMessage>();
```

now XMLMessage has set and get methods in here such as setFileContent, setFileName, and setFileDirectory and these are all Strings.

So how do I access those setmethods?

I am guessing it's something like this?

List xmlMessageList = new ArrayList();
      xmlMessageList.add(setFileContent);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a specific `XMLMessage` from the list by using the get `get(int)` method. You can then call methods on this instance. E.g.:

```
List<XMLMessage> xmlMessageList = new ArrayList<>();
xmlMessageList.add(new XMLMessage());

XMLMessageList.get(0).setFileName("my_file.txt");
```